# Nuget doesn't seem to be installing header files

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm new to the Nuget package manager (Maven guy normally, trying to fix a project my boss set up). Our project requires boost and openssl. Currently someone has to have boost and openssl installed on their system. I am hoping to use nuget to install the dependencies so that we can just clone-and-build anywhere that has VS2015.

But I can't make it work. Even installing the Boost headers and boost-vc140 packages, my project is still reporting `Cannot open include file: 'boost/noncopyable.hpp': No such file or directory` with the include `#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>`.

I've tried upgrading to the newest version of nuget (the previous one ships with VS2015), I've installed all the boost nuget libraries, and just generally beat my head against this for the last day. This seems way more difficult than it should be to add dependencies to a project.

I also have no idea what openssl project to select.

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you find the header files noncopyable.hpp under the External Dependencies in the Solution Explorer? I have create a blank Win 32 project, add the boost package, build successfully with the include #include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>. You can also try this method on the new project to exclude the impact of environmental settings on the previous project, check if it works fine.

Comment: I've never seen such error. Could you create a simple project on GitHub and share it?